# how to get synonyms of 2 tokens with wordnet

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, wordnet

I want to get the exact synonyms for'project management'. My code is the following:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

word = wordnet.synsets('project_management')
print(word.lemma_names())
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please elaborate on `doesn't work`.

Answer (score 0):

The term "project management" is not in WordNet. Compare with this example:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

word = wordnet.synsets('new_york')
print(word)

print([w.lemma_names() for w in word])
```

(Note that `word` is a list, so you need to iterate through it, even when there is only one synset; you cannot apply `lemma_names()` directly.)

You can use the [WordNet web search](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=project%20management&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=000) when you are not sure if the problem is your data or your code.